# apex method receiving null value when passed string from lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

So, I am doing this:

```
this.pendingAction = promiseCache(getPromotions, {sellerId : this.item.seller_id, params : null} )
```

promiseCache is what is sounds like. I pass it the imported apex method I want to call imperatively, and the parameters. 'SellerId' is a String, as defined in the method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getPromotions(String sellerId, Map<String, Object> params){
    System.debug('lwcPromotionsController sellerId: ' + sellerId);
    String token = AppConnectionController.getTokenFromSeller(sellerId);
    MLPromotionManager manager = new MLPromotionManager(token); //pasarle token dsp
    return manager.userPromotionsRaw(sellerId, params); 
}
```

For some reason, in the debug it shows a null value. I already made a console.log of the value i'm passing (this.item.seller_id) and it looks fine, and checked what data type the field is in salesforce and it is a text field. What is happening?

EDIT: here is the promiseCache method, in case it has something to do with it:

```
async function promiseCache(promise, params) {
    params = params || {};
    promiseCache.cache = promiseCache.cache || new Map();
    promiseCache[promise] = promiseCache[promise] || {};

    const hash = JSON.stringify(params);

    if (!promiseCache.cache[promise][hash]) promiseCache.cache[promise][hash] = promise(params);
    return promiseCache.cache[promise][hash];
}
```

Comment: Wonder if you are getting a circular reference in the params stringify? You have params, with params as a var in params...

Comment: Also, try the call without your promise cache... you can specify the AuraEnabled method to be cacheable too you know

Comment: making the auraenabled cacheable does the same thing as the promiseCache method?? (I didn't write that code, that's why I'm asking)

Comment: Yep. Sure does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `promiseCache` function isn't waiting for the results, so it returns null. You need to wait (using `await`):

```
async function promiseCache(promise, params) {
    params = params || {};
    promiseCache.cache = promiseCache.cache || new Map();
    promiseCache[promise] = promiseCache[promise] || {};

    const hash = JSON.stringify(params);

    if (!promiseCache.cache[promise][hash]) {
      promiseCache.cache[promise][hash] = await promise(params);
    }
    return promiseCache.cache[promise][hash];
}
```

In addition, you need to do the same for your method call:

```
this.pendingAction = await this.promiseCache(getPromotions, {sellerId : this.item.seller_id, params : null} )
```

The method this is contained in also needs to be `async`.

P.S. All this code is mostly useless, as `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` automatically does what you're trying to do here, with an appropriate stale time so you can get fresh values later. I'd recommend ditching this and just using the promise directly.

```
this.pendingAction = await getPromotions(
  {sellerId : this.item.seller_id, params : null }
);
```